# Move Skeptics from Culture/Recreation to the Science category

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

The footer with the list of sites looks like it is going to be updated, at least there is a new version of it visible on Meta.SO. In that version, the sites are separated according to the Area 51 categories.

This makes sense in general of course, but Skeptics is in the category Culture/Recreation, and I don't think it belongs there. We have been in the wrong category for a while, but those categories didn't reall matter outside of Area 51. Now that they are going to be visible on the main sites, we should move into the proper "Science" category where we belong.

Comment: Yes – but is here the right place to raise this? Wouldn’t this be a support question and thus for http://meta.stackoverflow.com? (Or should this be tagged “discussion”, in which case we could argue whether it’s more relevant to leave it in the “culture” section …)

Comment: This is only relevant for our site, so I think this is the appropriate place. Once the Skeptics community shows that it supports the change, we can point someone from SE to this post. Or if the community doesn't approve, we leave the site where it is now.

Comment: @Fabian do you want the footer to be changed only on skeptics or on all graduated sites? If it's on all sites then this question belongs on meta.

Comment: @Sklivvz I want Skeptics to be put into a different site category. That this also changes the footer is a side-effect. The main question here is "in which category does Skeptics belong", and I think the Skeptics community is more relevant to this than the whole SE community.

Comment: @Fabian there is no "site category" as such, there's just a footer (an HTML block).

Comment: @Sklivvz The categories are on Area 51, there every site is put into one category. The new footer is just the first time those categories are visible outside of Area 51 and stackexchange.com, they never really mattered before

Comment: @Fabian as far as I know, they are unrelated. There is no "shared" category across Area51, SE.com, meta and sites...

Comment: @Sklivvz The Area 51 categories match the footer categories perfectly, just some categories are combined like Culture and Recreation, and Life and Arts. [Skeptics also appears in the categorie Culture on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/3/culture), so they certainly look related, even if they are implemented differently

Comment: Why does Skeptics.SE belong in the science category?

Answer (score 7):

I agree with your proposal.

Furthermore we should move philosophy to culture (philosophy is most certainly NOT a science).

Comment: Well. Scepticism is also not a science. It *applies* science. But then so can philosophy (but traditionally doesn’t).

Comment: Philosophy is closer to culture, skepticism is closer to science. IMO

Comment: Maybe we should ask [Philosophy.se] where they believe they fit best?

Comment: @Aarthi we most definitely should, which is why I wanted to move the question to main meta :-) But, we should at least ask them if they feel their current placement is appropriate.

Comment: I agree with your first sentence, I do not agree or disagree with the second. As a result, I am not upvoting.

Comment: @Suma why not add your own answer then?

Answer (score 7):

To be honest, I'm going to have to go against the grain and disagree on this one although with the caveat that I'm not sure that "Culture / Recreation" is the right category either. The reason why I don't think that "Science" is the best category is that while most of the focus of this site is on science related questions, we still welcome and address questions related to [history](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10298/did-the-computing-term-bug-come-from-a-moth-stuck-in-a-computer) and [popular culture](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/was-there-an-expressionless-woman-admitted-to-cedar-senai-hospital-in-la-in-19) that are only nominally related (at best) to science. Thus, I'd be concerned that moving us to "Science" would change the nature of the questions that we would get.

Although that said, I wonder if "Life / Arts" might be a choice to consider since the site tends encourage a skeptical approach to pretty much everything as opposed to just a narrow band of things.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with your proposal. It seems to me science describes this site better than culture or recreation.

Comment: I agree with your answer because it's a subset of mine. +1 :-)

Answer (score 3):

We're not going to be making any category changes at the moment.

Our Area 51 categorization is admittedly a bit arbitrary, but I don't think Science makes any more sense for this site than Culture/Recreation does. Skepticism isn't really a science or an academic field.  Rather it's a *world view* that happens to be really important to the scientific method.

To be honest, I don't think we currently *have* a category that would be a clear and obvious winner for Skeptics. We've talked briefly about re-evaluating the categories we have on hand, but that's been on hold as most Area 51-related things are right now.

Comment: Have you read [Scientific Skepticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_skepticism)?

Comment: "Scientific skeptics believe that empirical investigation of reality leads to the truth, and that the scientific method is best suited to this purpose."

Comment: Skepticism is a world view that believes the use of the scientific method is the best route to truth.

Comment: @Articuno It's still a *world view*, not a science.

Comment: I didn't think that precludes it from being accurately categorized.

Comment: @Articuno That's assuming you and I agree that "science" is the right category. My point is that it isn't.

Comment: Ah. okay. So, it's really not up to the individual sites how they are categorized, then? (at least, not at the moment)

Comment: @Articuno That's typically settled during the site definition process, which is how Skeptics ended up in its current category.

Comment: Has any site ever changed its category after the definition process? Just curious what it would take...

Comment: It's not impossible in principle, but I don't think we've ever had a precedent. In this case, we (the community team at SE) discussed this request internally and it wasn't clear to us that Science is an obvious win.

Comment: Okay, I just was trying to understand the process. If I understand you correctly, the decision is simply not in the hands of this site's community. That's okay, I guess, since the SE community team needs to decide what's best for the stackexchange network as a whole, and I can see how categorization decisions affect the network more than they affect any individual site (except for maybe a bit of traffic being misdirected).